# Reading Events from CSV file into ESPER with POJO

Tags: csv, esper

Reading Events from CSV file into ESPER with POJO, the code below seams to scan through the file (larger files take longer), however no output is generated by events reaching listener.

the CSV file content is:
Geotimestamp,closeoutBid,closeoutAsk,tradable
"20170301 000000643",1.236550,1.236680,0
"20170301 000001893",1.236540,1.236680,0
"20170301 000002893",1.236550,1.236680,0
"20170301 000004410",1.236560,1.236700,0
"20170301 000006160",1.236540,1.236680,0
"20170301 000006393",1.236540,1.236670,0

The code is based on article [here](http://andreamconnell.blogspot.com/2012/02/working-with-esper-problems-and.html)

```
import com.espertech.esper.client.*;
import com.espertech.esperio.csv.AdapterInputSource;
import com.espertech.esperio.csv.CSVInputAdapter;
import com.espertech.esperio.csv.CSVInputAdapterSpec;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout;

import java.io.File;
import java.time.Instant;


public class hAppY implements Runnable {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AppMod.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();
        ConsoleAppender appender = new ConsoleAppender(new SimpleLayout());
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender);
        Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel((Level) Level.WARN);

        new AppMod().run();
    }

    public hAppY() {
    }

    public void run() {

        //The Configuration is meant only as an initialization-time object.
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        // We register Ticks as objects the engine will have to handle
        configuration.addEventType("HistData", HistDataEventClass.class);//.getName()

        EPServiceProvider epService = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(configuration);


        File file = new File("./data/DAT_ASCII_GBPUSD_T_201703.csv");
        AdapterInputSource ais = new AdapterInputSource(file);

        CSVInputAdapterSpec spec = new CSVInputAdapterSpec(ais, "HistDataEventClass");
        spec.setUsingExternalTimer(true); //will not pause for time between ticks when true

        EPAdministrator epAdmin = epService.getEPAdministrator();
        String vel1 = "select count(*) from HistData()";//()from HistData().win:time(3 sec)";
        EPStatement cepStatement1 = epAdmin.createEPL(vel1);
        //attach 1st statement listener to cep statement obj
        cepStatement1.addListener(new CEPListener());

        (new CSVInputAdapter(epService, ais,"HistDataEventClass")).start();
    }



    public class HistDataEventClass {

        private java.lang.String /*Instant*/ Geotimestamp; 
        private java.lang.String receivedTS;
        private double closeoutBid; 
        private double closeoutAsk;
        private byte tradable; //ignore


//c'tor

        public HistDataEventClass(java.lang.String timestamp, java.lang.Double closeoutBid, java.lang.Double closeoutAsk, byte tradable) {

            try {
                this.receivedTS = Instant.now().toString(); //received time stamp at time of instantiation of event object (this)
                this.Geotimestamp = timestamp;
                // NEED TO PROPERLY PARSE THE TS
                this.closeoutBid = Double.parseDouble(java.lang.String.valueOf(closeoutBid));
                this.closeoutAsk = Double.parseDouble(java.lang.String.valueOf(closeoutAsk));
                this.tradable = tradable;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        // getters/setters
        //timestamp
        public java.lang.String getTimestamp() {
            return this.Geotimestamp;
        }
        public void setGeoTimestamp(String ts) {this.Geotimestamp = ts;}

        // receivedTS
        public java.lang.String getReceivedTS() {return this.receivedTS;}
        public void setReceivedTS(String rts) {this.receivedTS = rts;}

        //CloseoutBid()
        public double getCloseoutBid() {return this.closeoutBid;}
        public void setCloseoutBid(double bid){this.closeoutBid=bid;}

        //CloseoutAsk()
        public double getCloseoutAsk() {return this.closeoutAsk;}
        public void setCloseoutAsk(double ask){this.closeoutAsk=ask;}

        //tradable()
        public byte getTradable() {return this.tradable;}
        public void setTradable(byte t){this.tradable=t;}
    }




    public class CEPListener implements UpdateListener { //removed static to satisfy compiler
        public void update(EventBean[] newData, EventBean[] oldData) {
            System.out.println("my print statement: " + newData[0].getUnderlying());
        }
    }//CEPListener

}
```

Comment: Is there any exception logged or thrown?

Comment: No exception thrown

Comment: perhaps your logging is not configured correctly. The CSVInputAdapter takes an event type name i.e. "HistData" would seem right